# Buggy behavior of tkzMarkAngle

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I'm trying to mark an angle on a 3d plot with `\tkzMarkAngle` which seems to behave quite oddly in combination with `\tdplotsetmaincoords`

Here's what I mean, below is the minimal example:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{0}{315}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
  \coordinate (OX) at (1,0,0);
  \coordinate (OO) at (0,0,0);
  \coordinate (OY) at (0,1,0);
  \tkzMarkAngle[fill=purple](OX,OO,OY)
  \draw (OY) -- (OO) -- (OX);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I'm simply trying to draw an angle and mark it with a filled arc. However what I get is the following:

[image: An angle and an arc].

Seems like the arc is rotated twice the angle it should be.
Does anyone else have the same result? Or is it me having a buggy version of tikz?.

I'm running on OSX, latex and tikz installed through macports.

Thanks.

UPD1. Here's how a 20 degrees rotation looks (`\tdplotsetmaincoords{0}{20}`):

[image: Angle and an arc 2]

Comment: Is not a bug. `\tkzMarkAngle` doesn't respond to 
`\tdplotsetmaincoords{0}{315}` (why should it?).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Well, if it didn't respond I would expect the arc to face right side, not left. I also updated the post with what a 20 degree rotation looks like.

Comment: @SiLiKhon Hmmm... I see your point now. Yes, there seems to be some problem with `\tkzMarkAngle`. I proposed an alternative approach below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned, there seems to be an odd behaviour of `\tkzMarkAngle` and `\tdplotsetmaincoords`. As a work-around, you could use the `angles` library:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{0}{315}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
  \coordinate (OX) at (1,0,0);
  \coordinate (OO) at (0,0,0);
  \coordinate (OY) at (0,1,0);
%  \tkzMarkAngle[fill=purple](OX,OO,OY)
  \draw (OY) -- (OO) -- (OX)
     pic[fill=purple!20,angle radius=9mm] {angle = OX--OO--OY};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

A longer example; the `bending` library was added to improve the look for the curved arrows:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,bending}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{30}{120}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  tdplot_main_coords,
  markangle/.style={draw,->,>=latex}
]
  \coordinate (OX) at (1,0,0);
  \coordinate (OO) at (0,0,0);
  \coordinate (OY) at (0,1,0);
  \coordinate (OZ) at (0,0,2);
  \path
    pic[fill=purple!20,angle radius=5mm,markangle] {angle = OY--OO--OZ}
    pic[fill=green!20,angle radius=5mm,markangle] {angle = OX--OO--OY}
    pic[fill=blue!20,angle radius=5mm,markangle] {angle = OZ--OO--OX};
  \draw 
    (OX) -- (OO) 
    (OY) -- (OO) 
    (OZ) -- (OO); 
%  \tkzMarkAngle[fill=purple](OX,OO,OY)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks nice, thanks a lot! Is it also possible to draw an arrow arc with this library? Like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/lOWYu.png

Comment: @SiLiKhon You're welcome. Sure it's possible. See my updated answer (drop the `fill=<color>` options if you don't want the filling).

Answer (score 2):

Certainly a bug. You can the new version of tkz-euclide v2.42 (beta) [here](http://altermundus.fr/files/euclide/geom_2.42b.zip)

[image]